# Weird Array/String Return in PHP - Can't parse it to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing

So I've got a series of what seem to be arrays coming out of CSV document. The farthest I can break it down is to this:

`a:11:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:"name";s:10:"First Name";s:5:"value";s:4:"Mark"}i:10;b:0;}`

I'm not sure how to get these strings/arrays to be at associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is a serialized PHP array. You can use [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to restore the array. After that `$array[0]["name"]` will equal to *First Name* for example.

Answer (score 0):

That's PHP's `serialize` format. Step 1, complain to whoever sent you the file for using a format not intended for interchange; step 2, use [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize) to decode it.